# Override default log location for JMeter when launching with Java (not command line)

Tags: java, jmeter

Is there an equivalent of the -j command-line option when launching JMeter using Java?

I'm running a series of test scripts that each need to have a custom log name - normally I'd just define each log location using -j, but in these cases they need to be launched through Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you have possibility to amend the java code and invoke [System.setProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) function :

   ```
   System.setProperty("jmeter.logfile", "/desired/path/to/jmeter.log)"
   ```
2. If you don't:

   - either pass the property via `-D` command line argument like:

     ```
     java -Djmeter.logfile=/desired/path/to/jmeter.log ....
     ```
   - or add the next line to *system.properties* file:

     ```
     jmeter.logfile=/desired/path/to/jmeter.log
     ```

More information:

- [JMeter Properties Reference](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html)

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I was having extra issues as I hadn't defined the location of the log4j2.xml file yet, but once I sorted that this fix worked perfectly.